# How to create functions in the global scope based on name, calling a method by same name

Tags: python, logging, dry, python-2.6

I'm trying to generate a bunch of functions based on the respective methods of a  [`logging.Logger`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) instance from inside a function scope. The functions/methods I am interested in are:

```
['debug', 'info', 'warning', 'error', 'critical', 'exception']
```

which all share the same prototype.

Now I can obviously state:

```
global debug, info, warning, error critical, exception
```

and then go ahead and `def` each of them. I checked it and that works fine. Problem is that I have to repeat myself.

So I have an instance of a `logging.Logger` named `mylog` which is already a global. The following does what I want, but by hardcoding the name of the function/method respectively:

```
global debug
def debug(msg, *args, **kwargs):
    if mylog: mylog.debug(msg, *args, **kwargs)
```

For the sake of brevity I'm going to write my examples all with only `debug` in mind, skipping the rest. Unfortunately the real code is somewhat more complex so that the requirements for using a `lambda` don't seem to be fulfilled (single statement, right?).

So my obvious thinking was to use `getattr` with the name of `"debug"` on `mylog` and simply call whatever I get back inside the defined function and add that by name to the `globals()` `dict`. Example:

```
for fct in ['debug']:
    def x(msg, *args, **kwargs):
        if mylog: getattr(mylog, fct)(msg, *args, **kwargs)
    globals()[fct] = x
```

But I think this is not actually legal as I am calling what's supposed to be a class method as if it were a static method. Nevertheless this "works", but each output line is followed by another line saying: `None`.

So I thought to myself that I could possibly pass the instance as the first parameter. After all that's what the `self` is all about:

```
for fct in ['debug']:
    def x(msg, *args, **kwargs):
        if mylog: getattr(mylog, fct)(mylog, msg, *args, **kwargs)
    globals()[fct] = x
```

which gives me:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

which is the identical effect that I get from this:

```
for fct in ['debug']:
    import types
    def x(msg, *args, **kwargs):
        if mylog: types.MethodType(getattr(mylog, fct), mylog)(msg, *args, **kwargs)
    globals()[fct] = x
```

which I based on the accepted answer of this question: [Dynamically bind method to class instance in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8980676)

Applying the answer from Alex Martelli [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1015405) gives the same error.

What am I doing wrong? How can I achieve the desired behavior without having to repeat myself?

---

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 776, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 654, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 436, in format
    record.message = record.getMessage()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 306, in getMessage
    msg = msg % self.args
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Complete script, based on the very first example code above:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, logging

def setup_logging():
    global mylog
    mylog = logging.getLogger('foobar')
    mylog.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
    for fct in ['debug']:
        def x(msg, *args, **kwargs):
            if mylog: getattr(mylog, fct)(mylog, msg, *args, **kwargs)
        globals()[fct] = x

def main():
    setup_logging()
    debug('TEST LOG MESSAGE')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: Can you include the full traceback for the "not all arguments" error?

Comment: @NedBatchelder: not sure how this would help, since this is in library modules, but here you go :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that this ought to work:

```
debug = mylog.debug
```

or:

```
debug, info, warning, error, critical, exception = (
    mylog.debug, mylog.info, mylog.warning, 
    mylog.error, mylog.critical, mylog.exception)
```

To set it dynamically:

```
for fct in ('debug', 'info', 'warning'):
    globals()[fct] = getattr(mylog, fct)
```

Your for loops `for fct in ('debug'):` are iterating over the string `'debug'`, you would have needed a comma `for fct in ('debug',):` to make it a tuple.

Also note that a construct such as:

```
for fct in ['debug']:
    def x(msg, *args, **kwargs):
        if mylog: getattr(mylog, fct)(msg, *args, **kwargs)
    globals()[fct] = x
```

defines a function uses the current value of `fct`` when it is called. You need an extra level of indirection to handle more than one logging method. e.g.

```
def make_log(fct):
    def x(msg, *args, **kwargs):
        if mylog: getattr(mylog, fct)(msg, *args, **kwargs)
    return x

for fct in ['debug','info']:
    globals()[fct] = make_log(fct)
```

Comment: thanks for your time. This dodges the question, though, how to do it based on the name (or "dynamically"). But it *is* less verbose, which is also cool.

Comment: OMG. I just realized. My own example used several entries. A list also works or `('debug', )`. Trying your method now. Corrected the examples in my question.

Comment: the way you're setting it dynamically works, of course. But doesn't take into account that I need some extra stuff in the code, which was represented by the `if mylog:` in my question. Still +1 for all your efforts.

Comment: awesome, thanks. it was the fact that I didn't use another level of abstraction that tripped me up, from how I understand it.