# How to use yield in BinarySearchTree?

Tags: python, binary-search-tree, yield

I am following the BinarySearchTree code in the book [Data Structure and Algorithms](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319130712).
Would you like to read the full code in [this link](https://kentdlee.github.io/CS2Plus/build/html/chap6/chap6.html#binary-search-trees)?

And I am not clear how this method works

```
def __iter__(self):
   if self.left != None:
      for elem in self.left:
         yield elem
                    
      yield self.val
            
   if self.right != None:
      for elem in self.right:
         yield elem
```

1. Is the **elem** variable an instance of the **Node** class or is it a float number (from inputs)? In debug it is both, I guess this value is changed because of line *yield elem* but I do not understand it.
2. What are the differences between *yield elem* and *yield self.val*? How many generator objects are there in this situation?
3. In addition, would you like to share some experience in debugging generator functions? I am confused by *yield* when debugging.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>1. `elem` is a `Node` instance. From the for loops, we know that `elem` is always either `self.left` or `self.right`. You can see in the example usage that float values are inserted into the binary tree with `tree.insert(float(x))` and the `BinarySearchTree.insert()` method ultimately calls `BinarySearchTree.Node(val)` where `val` is `float(x)` in this case. Therefore `self.left` and `self.right` are always `Node` instances.</strike>

1. As mentioned by don't talk just code in the comments, `elem` is a float. I did not see this before because I assumed that iterating over `self.left` would product a list of `Node` elements. However this is not correct. In fact, iterating over `self.left` works in this case by calling `self.left.__iter__()`. I break down this `__iter__()` function into 3 cases, almost like a recursive function. (It is not in fact recursive because it is calling the `__iter__()` method of different instances of the `Node` class, but its behavior is similar.)

   - First, the Node has no `left` or `right` children. This is straightforward: the iter will just yield `self.val`, which is a float.
   - Second, the Node has `left` children. In this case, the for loop will  traverse down all the left children in an almost recursive fashion until it reaches a Node that has no `left` children. Then we are back at the first case.
   - Third, the Node has `right` children. In this case, after the own nodes `self.val` is return, the iterator will continue to the first `right` node, and repeat.
2. There is only one [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#generator-types), namely `Node.__iter__()`, because generators are functions. It uses multiple `yield` statements to return different values depending on the situation. `yield elem` and `yield self.val` just return either a `Node` if the current Node has left or right branches or the current Node's value.
3. I do not have specific tips for debugging `yield` statements in particular. In general I use [IPython](https://ipython.org/) for interactive work when building code and use its built-in [`%debug` magic operator](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html?highlight=%25debug#magic-debug). You might also find [rubber duck debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) useful.

Using IPython you can run the following in a cell to debug interactively.

```
In [37]: %%debug
    ...: for x in tree.root:
    ...:     print(x)
    ...:
NOTE: Enter 'c' at the ipdb>  prompt to continue execution.
```

You can then use the `s` command at the debugger prompt, `ipdb>` , to step through the code, jumping into a function calls.

```
ipdb> s
--Call--
> <ipython-input-1-c4e297595467>(30)__iter__()
     28         # of the nodes of the tree yielding all the values. In this way, we get
     29         # the values in ascending order.
---> 30         def __iter__(self):
     31             if self.left != None:
     32                 for elem in self.left:
```

While debugging, you can evaluate expressions by preceding them with an exclamation point, `!`.

```
ipdb> !self
BinarySearchTree.Node(5.5,BinarySearchTree.Node(4.4,BinarySearchTree.Node(3.3,BinarySearchTree.Node(2.2,BinarySearchTree
.Node(1.1,None,None),None),None),None),None)
```

Comment: "`elem` is a `Node` instance." - It clearly isn't.

Comment: They ask "How many generator **objects**", rather likely meaning the iterators, not the function (They also do say "generator functions" later on).

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode would you elaborate on why *elem* is not a *Node* instance?

Comment: Because it's a `self.val` from a deeper iteration.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode there is imprecision in the language used here. "Objects are Python’s abstraction for data" (from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html)). On that page it lists [generator functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#generator-types). And the return value of generator functions is a [generator iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-iterator). Thus I interpreted "generator object" to be the "generator function"

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode No, the `elem` object is only used in the `for` loops, which iterate over elements in `self.left` or `self.right`. Yes, the generator iterator will yield `self.val` after going through every element in `self.left`, but `self.val` is never assigned to `elem`.

Comment: If you don't see it by reading the code, then just execute it with an added `print(type(elem))` and you'll see it's not a `Node` instance.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode, you were right. I executed the code as you suggested which revealed I was thinking about this too superficially. I have edited my answer to strike out my incorrect answer.

Comment: Interesting thought about recursiveness. I still think the function is recursive, though. As [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) says: *"When an instance method object is called, the underlying function (__func__) is called, inserting the class instance (__self__) in front of the argument list."*.

Comment: Thanks for that quote from the documentation. I agree with you that the function looks recursive. Indeed, if I bind a new function (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980676/dynamically-bind-method-to-class-instance-in-python) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/adding-a-method-to-an-existing-object-instance)) to the `__iter__()` method of an instance of Node, it looks like the class's `__iter__()` is still called with the instance, e.g. `Node.__iter__(mynode)`

Answer (score 2):

First, there is an indentation issue in the code you shared: `yield self.val` should not be in the `if` block:

```
def __iter__(self):
   if self.left != None:
      for elem in self.left:
         yield elem
                    
   yield self.val  #  Unconditional. This is also the base case
            
   if self.right != None:
      for elem in self.right:
         yield elem
```

To understand this code, first start imagining a tree with just one node. Let's for a moment ignore the `BinarySearchTree` class and say we have direct access to the `Node` class. We can create a node and then iterate it:

```
node = Node(1)
for value in node:
    print(value)
```

This loop will call the `__iter__` method, which in this case will not execute any of the `if` blocks, as it has no children, and only execute `yield self.val`. And that is what `value` in the above loop will get as value, and which gets printed.

Now extend this little exercise with 2 more nodes:

```
node = Node(1, 
    Node(0),
    Node(2)
)
for value in node:
    print(value)
```

Here we have created this tree, and `node` refers to its root

```
     1   <-- node
    / \
   0   2
```

When the `for..in` loop will call `__iter__` now, it will first enter the first `if` block, where we get a form of *recursion*. With the `for` statement there, we again execute `__iter__`, but this time on the left child of `node`, i.e. the node with value 0. But that is a case we already know: this node has no children, and we know from the first example above, that this results in one iteration where the loop variable will be the value of that node, i.e. 0, and that value is yielded. That means the main program gets an iteration with `value` equal to 0, which gets printed.

So `elem` is numeric. It would better have been called `value` or `val` to take away any confusion.

After that `if` block has executed we get to `yield self.val`. `self` is here `node`, and so we yield 1. That means the main program gets to execute a second iteration, this time with `value` equal to 1.

Finally the second `if` block is executed, and now the right child of `node` is the subject of a recursive `__iter__` call. It is the same principle as with the left child. This yields value 2, and the main program prints 2.

We could again extend the tree with more nodes, but the principle is the same: by recursive calls of `__iter__` all the values of the tree are yielded.

#### `yield from`

There is a syntax that allows simplification of the code, and also it is more common practice to use the `is` operator when comparing with `None`:

```
def __iter__(self):
   if self.left is not None:
      yield from self.left
                    
   yield self.val
            
   if self.right is not None:
      yield from self.right
```

This results in the same behavior. `yield from` will yield all values that come from the iterable. And since node instances are iterable as they have the `__iter__` method, this works as intended.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Why is elem **val**  attribute? the *Node* Class has other as **left** and **right**

Comment: Do you know any special way to debug for **yield statement** in code?

Comment: It yields `val` because it is literally there in the code. It is the base case. All yields translate to that base case. I thought my answer took it step by step to explain how it comes to yield the values.

Comment: To debug, just `print(elem)` before the `yield elem`. For a big tree, you will then see the same value being printed multiple times, because one `yield` will cause `yield` to happen in the whole path of the recursion tree.